# Show that $H^1(U,\mathbb{C})\cong \mathbb{C}^n$.

Tags: complex-analysis, homology-cohomology

Let $\Omega$ be the open set in $\mathbb{C}$ given by $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{a_1,\dots, a_n\}$ where the $a_i$ are distinct points. Let $U$ be a cover of $\Omega$ by disks. Show that $H^1(U,\mathbb{C})\cong \mathbb{C}^n$ (as $\mathbb{C}$-vector spaces) where $H^1$ is the Cech cohomology, as defined in Narasimhan's *Complex Analysis in One Variable*.

Some remarks:

We know that we have an exact sequence $0\to \mathbb{C}\to \mathcal{O}(\Omega)\to \mathcal{O}(\Omega)\to H^1(U,\mathbb{C})\to 0$ where the second arrow is the obvious inclusion, the third arrow is differentiation, and the fourth arrow is the standard homomorphism $\partial$ (defined via diagram chase). (This is just the Cohomology Form of Cauchy's Theorem.)

In turn, one possible approach is to simply show that the vector space $\partial \mathcal{O}(\Omega)$ has dimension $n$. But it is not clear how one would do this to me.

Alternatively, this problem is equivalent to computing the cokernel of the $d/dz$ map, which could perhaps be done using some abstract nonsense, although this approach is also opaque to me.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have undeleted this question. I notice that you deleted this question shortly after receiving an answer. This is very unkind to your answerer and to later visitors of the site.  It also makes it appear as though you are trying to hide something. **Don't do that**.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the map $\rho:\mathcal O(\Omega)\to\Bbb C^n$ where we take an $f$ to $(r_1,\ldots,r_n)$
where $r_i$ is the residue of $f(z)\,dz$ at $a_i$. The kernel of this map is
the image of the differentiation map $d:\mathcal O(\Omega)\to\mathcal O(\Omega)$.
Therefore the image of $\rho$ is isomorphic to the cokernel of $d$. But $\rho$
is surjective: consider the functions $1/(z-a_i)$.